# Is there a way to install Unity 7 or 8 in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: unity, 17.10

I know Ubuntu 17.10 has GNOME shell 3.26 entirely replacing Unity 8, and I also know at this point Ubuntu 17.10 hasn't been released, but I still asked here for people in the future that may get confused with the replacement of GNOME.

Now, I have been searching in `artful` repositories everywhere, finding something that I am concerned about:

1. GNOME shell 3.26 is now the default Ubuntu desktop environment, and I still find a package called `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` in `artful`'s `Universe` Repository. What is this package for when GNOME has already become the default Ubuntu desktop environment?
2. Another concern to me is: `ubuntu-desktop` is now providing GNOME desktop environment instead of the Unity one. Is there any **offical** (Canonial-developed) version of Unity 8 available now, or, maybe available in the future, in the `artful` repository? If yes, how can I install it? (I am asking both Unity 7 and Unity 8)
3. I understand that there are community-developed versions of Unity, including `yunit` and `Artemis`. Is there other community-developed versions of Unity available elsewhere? Also, what is the difference between Canonial-developed Unity and all community-developed versions of Unity?
4. Refer to 2. . Is there any source code for Canonial-developed Unity 7 and 8 that I can build in Ubuntu 17.10 and it will run on Ubuntu 17.10 smoothly? If yes, where can I find it? Also, how to build Unity 7 and 8 from source code? It is better if there is a complete guide.
5. Is there a way to get the source code of Unity from previous versions of Ubuntu? Will it run on Ubuntu 17.10 like the previous versions of Ubuntu?

This will take a long time to solve, I know, but any great help and contribution to Ask Ubuntu will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Consider asking splitting it into separate smaller questions.

Comment: You can install `unity` package on 17.10, it is in repositories.